# Special attached property binding works, but not in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, dependency-properties

## Goal

My goal is to be able to give my code a reference to a UI element via a binding (as opposed to giving the element a `Name` or having to walk through the visual tree manually to find it).

To that end, I've created a special attached dependency property called `Self`. It's based off the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58144080/5086631). It's intended to be special in two ways:

1. The value of `Self` should always be a reference to the element on which it is set. So if `Self` is used on a `Button`, the value of `Self` should always return a reference to said `Button`.
2. The `Self` property, when bound to, should push its value onto the binding source.

Basically, you should be able to do this:

```
<Button Name="A" local:BindingHelper.Self="{Binding Foo.Button}"/>
```

And `Foo.Button` would then be given the `Button` `A` object as its value.

## Main Code

To accomplish this, I've adapted the code from the [previously mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58144080/5086631) and created this:

```
Public Class BindingHelper
    Public Shared ReadOnly SelfProperty As DependencyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Self", GetType(DependencyObject), GetType(BindingHelper),
                                                New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                              AddressOf Self_PropertyChanged, AddressOf Self_CoerceValue))

    Public Shared Function GetSelf(element As DependencyObject) As DependencyObject
        Return element.GetValue(SelfProperty)
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub SetSelf(element As DependencyObject, value As DependencyObject)
        element.SetValue(SelfProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub Self_PropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        If e.NewValue IsNot d Then UpdateSelfValue(d)
    End Sub

    Private Shared SelfCoercionInProgress As New HashSet(Of DependencyObject)

    Private Shared Function Self_CoerceValue(d As DependencyObject, baseValue As Object) As Object
        If baseValue IsNot d AndAlso Not SelfCoercionInProgress.Contains(d) Then
            SelfCoercionInProgress.Add(d)
            UpdateSelfValue(d)
            SelfCoercionInProgress.Remove(d)
        End If

        Return d
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub UpdateSelfValue(d As DependencyObject)
        Dim B = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, SelfProperty)

        If B IsNot Nothing AndAlso B.Status <> BindingStatus.Detached Then
            B.UpdateTarget()
            SetSelf(d, d)
            B.UpdateSource()
        Else
            SetSelf(d, d)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

## Code for testing and error reproduction

A simple `MainWindow.xaml.vb`:

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Property Foo As New Foo

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        'You can put a breakpoint here
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Foo
    Public Property Button As Button
End Class
```

And `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VBTest"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="A" local:BindingHelper.Self="{Binding Foo.Button}" Click="Button_Click">A</Button>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Foo}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<Button Name="B" local:BindingHelper.Self="{Binding Button}" Click="Button_Click">B</Button>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Notice that the `B` line in the `DataTemplate` is commented out. If you run the above code, it works as intended. `Foo.Button` is given a reference to `Button` `A`.

Now, comment out the `A` line and un-comment the `B` line. In theory, it should work exactly the same, all I've done is move the `Button` into a `DataTemplate`, but for some reason `Foo.Button` is never given a reference to `Button` `B`. This is the part I need help figuring out. Without being able to use this in a `DataTemplate`, I can never use it in an `ItemsControl`.

## My progress so far

The problem seems to have something to do with:

```
Dim B = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, SelfProperty)
```

This unexpectedly returns `Nothing` for `Button` `B`, so `UpdateSource` is never called. After initialization/loading is finished, if I try calling `GetBindingExpression` from a breakpoint, it returns the expected value, but for whatever reason it doesn't do so when the target is being initialized inside a `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out exactly why `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` was returning `Nothing` at that point, but I was able to come up with a reliable work-around. I did some extensive testing and mapped out the call stack, noting when `GetBindingExpression` started to return a value. I found that in my setup, `Self_PropertyChanged` would be called twice, but `GetBindingExpression` would only work on the second round. So I added code to track whether or not a binding existed during the previous call to `Self_PropertyChanged`, and if it didn't but one does exist now, then I run through the update procedure again.

Here's the full, working code for anyone interested:

```
Public Class BindingHelper
    Public Shared ReadOnly SelfProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Self", GetType(DependencyObject), GetType(BindingHelper),
                                            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                            AddressOf Self_PropertyChanged, AddressOf Self_CoerceValue))

    Public Shared Function GetSelf(element As DependencyObject) As DependencyObject
        Return element.GetValue(SelfProperty)
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub SetSelf(element As DependencyObject, value As DependencyObject)
        element.SetValue(SelfProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub Self_PropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim NeedToChange = e.NewValue IsNot d
        Dim B As BindingExpression

        If NeedToChange OrElse HadNoBindingOnLastChange.Contains(d) Then
            B = UpdateSelfValue(d, NeedToChange)
        Else
            B = GetActiveSelfBinding(d)
        End If

        If B Is Nothing Then
            HadNoBindingOnLastChange.Add(d)
        Else
            HadNoBindingOnLastChange.Remove(d)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared SelfCoercionInProgress As New HashSet(Of DependencyObject)
    Private Shared HadNoBindingOnLastChange As New HashSet(Of DependencyObject)
    Private Shared UpdatingWithBindingInProgress As New HashSet(Of DependencyObject)

    Private Shared Function Self_CoerceValue(d As DependencyObject, baseValue As Object) As Object
        If baseValue IsNot d AndAlso Not SelfCoercionInProgress.Contains(d) Then
            SelfCoercionInProgress.Add(d)
            UpdateSelfValue(d, True)
            SelfCoercionInProgress.Remove(d)
        End If

        Return d
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetActiveSelfBinding(d) As BindingExpression
        Dim B = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, SelfProperty)
        If B IsNot Nothing AndAlso B.Status = BindingStatus.Detached Then Return Nothing
        Return B
    End Function

    Private Shared Function UpdateSelfValue(d As DependencyObject, AlwaysSetSelf As Boolean) As BindingExpression
        Dim B = GetActiveSelfBinding(d)

        If B IsNot Nothing Then
            If UpdatingWithBindingInProgress.Add(d) Then
                B.UpdateTarget()
                SetSelf(d, d)
                UpdatingWithBindingInProgress.Remove(d)
            End If
        ElseIf AlwaysSetSelf Then
            SetSelf(d, d)
        End If

        Return B
    End Function
End Class
```

I've tested this, and it works inside or outside a `DataTempalte`, and also works to automatically change the source property back to the value of `Self` if said source property changes after initialization (provided the source supports change notification).

Interestingly, through my testing I found that the call to `UpdateSource` was completely unnecessary, since `SetSelf` always resulted in the source being updated. I removed that call which eliminated an unnecessary round of calls to the source's `Set` and `Get`, as well as `Self_CoerceValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this to work by telling `ContentControl` where to find the `Foo` property by adding:

> RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
```

Everything else is exactly the same as per your sample above.

Comment: This seems to work around the problem more than solve it. The binding already works fine without `RelativeSource`, because it's inheriting the `DataContext` from `MainWindow`. However, explicitly adding `RelativeSource` causes the binding engine to wait until later to actually try and resolve the binding. The result is that by the time the binding engine resolves the binding, `GetBindingExpression` is no longer returning `Nothing`.